# Java applets in windows store apps

Tags: applet, windows-8

I have a java applet and i'm developing a windows store app. I want to integrate my applet to this application. Is this feasible.. if yes... can you tell the process.

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be able to run your Java Applet into a `WebView` but I am not sure if that's a good practice or not. You should convert your java applet into a `HTML5/JavaScript` application or C# application for optimum performance.

Comment: Hi mayank.. using webview didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run this within a Windows Store application since plug-ins (you'd need Java installed) are not allowed for WebView (or for the non-desktop version of IE 10 in general - Flash excepted for some sites).

Comment: Is there any way for utilizing java applets in windows8 application

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment. When you were installing Java you must have missed the Java doesn't work in Metro.