# How to run a java applet on windows 8 mobile application using Phonegap / WinJs / C#

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I am developing one windows application for mobile and tablet devices.
I want to run one applet in the background or on web view and need to read some data from card reader (no other options or SDK available for this custom reader to read the data).

Using Applet, it's reading data and working fine but I want to run this applet in the background without moving the focus from my application or in a web view. 
am using Cordova, WinJS for development. and its only for windows 8+ devices.
I have tried using in-app browser and applet is not running on the in-app browser.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910463/java-applets-in-windows-store-apps

Comment: You could probably try to use websockets to connect the Java applet with Cordova application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, windows phone doesn't have a java virtual machine, so it's absolutely impossible to run java applets.